# Julia: vectorized version of searchsorted

Tags: julia

For each value in array `B`, how to find the closest value in array `A` with one function call, similar to how `searchsorted(A, B)` works in numpy.

Comment: You've received two good answers. I just wanted to point out that if `B` is sorted and (approximately) larger than `0.1*length(A)`, then you will get better performance with an algorithm that performs a single simultaneous loop over `A` and `B`. The single loop over both ends up having less operations than `length(B)` binary chops, which is what broadcasting over `searchsortedfirst` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
searchsortedfirst.(Ref(A),B)
```

should give you the desired result. Example:

```
julia> A = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 10];

julia> B = [10, 6, 9];

julia> searchsortedfirst.(Ref(A), B)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 10
  9
  9
```

Compare to `np.searchsorted`:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> np = pyimport("numpy");

julia> np.searchsorted(A,B)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 9
 8
 8
```

which (up to Python's 0-based indexing) is equivalent.

**Explanation:**
What does `searchsortedfirst.(Ref(A),B)` do?

The dot tells Julia to broadcast the `searchsortedfirst` call. However, we have to make sure that `A` is still treated as an array in each call (we want `A` to be a scalar under broadcasting). This can be achieved by wrapping `A` in a `Ref`.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a correct equivalent of numpy code, but please note (I was writing the answer in parallel) that the numpy code does not find what you want. In particular `searchsortedfirst` can return you out-of-bounds index.

Comment: Haven't you interchanged `A` and `B` here? At least according to the explanation in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `B` is unsorted (but then you cannot use `searchsorted` in numpy either) you can do:

```
[argmin(abs(a .- B)) for a in A]
```

If `B` is sorted and you accept that you do not find the closest value in array `B` (`searchsorted` does not find the closest value) you can write:

```
searchsorted.(Ref(B), A)
```

and you will get ranges in which elements of `A` sould be placed in `B` (you can also checkout functions `searchsortedfirst` and `searchsortedlast`)